# Javascript problems with HTML form

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I'm using javascript to change the appearance of this form, so that when you click a each radio button the "Body" input field changes size. The problem is that it only works when either none of the radio buttons are clicked or when I put a "checked" in one of the inputs in which case it only works for the checked input type. Here's the code:

```
<form action='add_note' method="POST">
    Title <input type="text" name="title" /><br />

    Body 
    <div id="note_input">
        <textarea id="note_input1" name="body" cols="27" rows="5"></textarea>
    </div>


    Type

    <input type="radio" name="typey" value="text" onclick="text_input_type('text')" checked/>
    Text

    <input type="radio" name="typey" value="list" onclick="text_input_type('list')"/>
    List

    <input type="radio" name="typey" value="checklist" onclick="text_input_type('checklist')" />
    Checklist 

    <input type="submit" name="addnote" value="Add Note" />
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
function text_input_type(type) {
    if (type=='list') {
        document.getElementById("note_input").innerHTML=
            "<input type=\"text\" id=\"note_input1\" name=\"body\">";
    }
    if(type == 'checklist') {
        document.getElementById("note_input").innerHTML=
            "<input type=\"text\" id=\"note_input1\" name=\"body\">";
    }
    if (type == 'text') {
        document.getElementById("note_input").innerHTML=
            "<textarea id=\"note_input1\" name=\"body\" cols=\"27\" rows=\"5\">
            </textarea>";
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Hi, I have put this into a jsFiddle for you: http://jsfiddle.net/bsLBm/.  Consider using it next time as it gives folks an instant demo and ability to tinker.

Comment: If you use a post bin such as jsfiddle, just make sure you still post the code on SO, as SO Q&As are meant to be standalone.

Comment: [`<br/>`](http://brainstormsandraves.com/articles/semantics/structure/#br) is rarely [semantic](http://webstyleguide.com/wsg3/5-site-structure/2-semantic-markup.html); use something more appropriate, such as a paragraph or [list](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/lists.html) element. On the topic of semantic HTML, the input label text should be in `<label>` elements.

Comment: Not sure what isn't working. `List` and `Checklist` are doing the same thing. See http://jsfiddle.net/giddygeek/hRxKL/ You are missing semicolons `;` in `onclick` . Also, you have just `checked` written incorrectly in your tag.

Comment: Instead of a sequence of `if` statements that all use equality comparisons, use a [`switch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch) statement. For a sequence of `if`s that require more than simple comparison, use `else if` for mutually exclusive cases.

Comment: The switching input sizes is working fine. The form just isn't processing correctly. The body field isn't carrying.

Comment: How, exactly, isn't it behaving as you expect? Saying something works or doesn't work tells us almost nothing.

Comment: I'm processing it with php. When the form is submitted to 'add_note.php' it returns "Notice: Undefined index: body in C:\xampp\htdocs\test4\add_note.php on line 8". I'm pretty sure this is because of the javascript, because it works when no radio buttons are pressed or when the radio button <input> in which "checked" was added is selected.

Comment: @CharlesMurray: please update the question with the requested information. In general, respond to requests for clarifications by updating your post, rather than replying with a comment. For one thing, a question should be understandable without reading comments. For another, SO is a Q&A site, not a forum, and comments aren't intended (nor are they well suited) for discussions.

Answer (score 0):

There's an error in your sample code, you shouldn't start a new line as below:

```
"<textarea id=\"note_input1\" name=\"body\" cols=\"27\" rows=\"5\">
</textarea>";
```

Comment: Which new line are you referring to?

Comment: Yes. Firebug show error on this line. It should be in one line.

Answer (score 0):

If you are allowed to user jQuery. It becomes very simple. Below trial code is only if you want to use jQuery.

(using switch case suggested by outis)

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function(){ 
  $("input[type='radio']").click(function(){      
    var type=$(this).attr('value');
    var target=$("#note_input");
    switch(type){
     case 'list':
        target.html("<input type=\"text\" id=\"note_input1\" name=\"body\">");
     break;  
     case 'checklist':
        target.html("<input type=\"text\" id=\"note_input1\" name=\"body\">");
     break;  
     case 'text': 
     target.html("<textarea id=\"note_input1\" name=\"body\" cols=\"27\" rows=\"5\"></textarea>");
     break;
    };
  });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form action='add_note' method="POST">
    Title <input type="text" name="title" /><br />
    Body 
    <div id="note_input">
        <textarea id="note_input1" name="body" cols="27" rows="5"></textarea>
    </div>
    Type
    <input type="radio" name="typey" value="text"/>
    Text
    <input type="radio" name="typey" value="list"/>
    List
    <input type="radio" name="typey" value="checklist"/>
    Checklist 
    <input type="submit" name="addnote" value="Add Note"/>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @CharlesMurray, pls explain what and when it doesn't work. May be you need something else.The code above works as per the logic.